# Can you easily test whether a method definition has changed, but a call to the method has not been updated (with Pytest and Mock)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following two methods (simplified):

```
def func_a(u, v, w, x, y, z):
    ##Do some irrelevant stuff
    newVariable = func_b(u, v, w, y)
    ##Do some more irrelevant stuff

def func_b(u, v, w, y):
    ##Do some manipulation of the variables
    ##Call some more methods, like func_c, func_d, func_e
    newVariable = 1 #In reality; some value that is calculated
    return newVariable
```

func_a is fairly simple, but func_b calls a few different methods according to some criteria, which are not relevant here. This function has a high probability of changing in the future, since it features calculations that might be changed at a later stage of the project. My problem is the following:

With Pytest and Mock, we can easily test the functionality of func_a; you can mock func_b and set the return_value.

It is also easy to check whether func_b is called correctly from func_a; with assert_called_with we can make sure the expected values are used when calling the function like so:

```
@patch('func_b') 
def test_func_a_calls_func_b_correctly(b_mock):
    func_a(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    b_mock.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

However, if we change the definition of func_b (for example to: `func_b(u, v, w, y, q)`, this test will still pass, since the call in func_a is still "as expected". This is of course not what we want, since the test will pass, but the program will crash when running it. Is there a way to test for a change of a method definition in this way?

If there is not, is the best possible test this NOT mocking func_b, but mocking func_c, func_d, and func_e that are called in func_b? This will of course work fine, but it does not seem very clean for a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a philosophical question as much as anything - `mock` isn't designed to emulate the function it is replacing, just provide a fake input and output to see how it is called.

If you do need to ensure that the calls your code makes to a function still 'match' the behaviour of the function, then you have to compare the original function to the `mock` (or the call) at the time of testing.

For example, in your current example, you could do:

```
from inspect import signature

@patch('func_b') 
def test_func_a_calls_func_b_correctly(b_mock):
    func_a(1,2,3,4,5,6)

    # Check that the number of params passed when calling func_b
    # is the same as the number of parameters that the 'real' func_b expects
    assert len(mock.call_args.args) == len(signature(func_b).parameters)
```

However, that doesn't protect against the order or 'purpose' of parameters changing, which would require further inspection of `func_b`.